# Why is $\Delta u \Delta v$ "negligible" for $d(uv)=\lim_{\Delta \to 0}{ \Delta (uv)}=\lim_{\Delta \to 0}{(u+\Delta u)(v+\Delta v)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Why is $\Delta u \Delta v$ "negligible" for $d(uv)=\lim_{\Delta \to 0}{ \Delta (uv)}=\lim_{\Delta \to 0}{(u+\Delta u)(v+\Delta v)}=\lim_{\Delta \to 0}{uv+\Delta uv+\Delta vu+\Delta u\Delta v}$?

If $\Delta \to 0$, why is $\Delta u\Delta v=0$ but $\Delta uv$ isn't?

This is part of the proof for the product rule.

Comment: Because derivatives are about linear approximations, so a product of "small" quantities is of quadratic order, and hence is negligible up to a first-order approximation. That being said, such a phrasing of the proof of the product rule is very imprecise. Have you seen the [proof in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Proof_by_factoring_(from_first_principles))?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite get what you just said in the first part of your sentence. I didn't mean that it's a part of my proof of the product rule but I saw this in another proof. @peek-a-boo

Comment: I would simply ignore such a non-rigorous, imprecise "proof". A proof is meant to be something that convinces you that something is true. If it doesn't make sense to you and you are aware of rigorous proofs that makes sense, like the standard one on wikipedia, then just ignore the hand-wavy one, otherwise you're wasting your time.

Comment: +1 for @AdamRubinson comment. Such non-rigorous stuff needs to be sent to trash.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Do you not think that is a good intuitive argument for why the product rule is true, just as $f(g(x+h))\approx f(g(x)+g'(x)h) \approx f(g(x))+f'(g(x))g'(x)h$ is a good intuitive argument for why the chain rule is true?

Comment: @Joe: I think it is better that we ditch the whole idea of approximations while teaching calculus. Their proper place should be in courses on numerical analysis. I have borne too much of this kind of stuff while studying calculus in high school.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I'm curious as to why you think that. For me at least, the notion of the derivative being the best linear approximation of a function at a given point is an extremely useful one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to *prove* the product rule, then the correct approach is not to dismiss $\Delta u\Delta v$ as "negligible", but rather rigorously show that $\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\Delta u\Delta v}{h}=0$. This should become clearer from the proof below.

The product rule states that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, and $g$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f \cdot g$ is differentiable at $a$, and
$$
(f \cdot g)'(a)=f(a)g'(a)+f'(a)g(a) \, .
$$
We can prove this using the definition of the derivative, writing $\Delta u$ for $f(a+h)-f(a)$ and $\Delta v$ for $g(a+h)-g(a)$:
\begin{align}
(f \cdot g)'(a) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)g(a+h)-f(a)g(a)}{h} \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\bigl(f(a)+\Delta u\bigr)\bigl(g(a)+\Delta v\bigr)-f(a)g(a)}{h} \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a)\Delta v+ g(a)\Delta u +\Delta u \Delta v}{h} \\[4pt]
&= f(a)\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Delta v}{h} + g(a)\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Delta u}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\Delta u \Delta v}{h} \, . \\[4pt] 
\end{align}
Thus, the value $(f \cdot g)'(a)$ depends on three limits: $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\Delta v}{h}$, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\Delta u}{h}$, and $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\Delta u \Delta v}{h}$. Since $\Delta v = g(a+h)-g(a)$ and $\Delta u = f(a+h)-f(a)$, the first two limits are $g'(a)$ and $f'(a)$ respectively. The third limit can be computed in the following way:
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\Delta u \Delta v}{h} &= \lim_{h \to 0}\Delta u \cdot \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\Delta v}{h} \\[4pt]
&= \lim_{h \to 0}\bigl(f(a+h)-f(a)\bigr) \cdot \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(a+h)-g(a)}{h} \\[4pt]
&= 0 \cdot g'(a) \\[4pt]
&= 0 \, .
\end{align}
Crucially, $\lim_{h \to 0}\bigl(f(a+h)-f(a)\bigr)=0$ because if a function is differentiable at $a$, then it is continuous at $a$. Wrapping up, we get that
$$
(f \cdot g)'(a) = f(a)g'(a) + f'(a)g(a) + 0 = f(a)g'(a) + f'(a)g(a) \, .
$$

Comment: Say $f(u,v)=uv \implies df(u,v)= \frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial f(u,v)}{\partial v}dv = udv + vdu$. Why is this not enough/would this be enough to show the above as well? Or is this a cyclic proof?

Comment: @j3141592653589793238: Your notation is not very clear to me, but the product rule can indeed be seen as a special case of the multivariable chain rule, though I am no expert on this.